# Beamer: effect of newline and hphantom

Tags: beamer, line-breaking

Why is it that the file

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    a\\
    \hphantom{ }b
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

produces an `a` and a `b` vertically aligned with a *line skip* in between whereas the same file with `\\` replaced by `\newline` produces the expected: an `a`, then a `b` on the next line, indented by one space?

Is that a bug in Beamer (in documentclass `Article`, both versions have the same, expected effect)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

I'd call this a feature of how `beamer` redefines `\\`. After it TeX is in vertical mode, so the `\hphantom`, which ultimately does `\box2` doesn't start horizontal mode.

Use

```
\leavevmode\hphantom{ }
```

Note that standard LaTeX doesn't start vertical mode after `\\`.

Comment: That's a strange vision of a 'feature' but ok, it makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: @mqtthiqs Well, our beloved moderator Joseph, who has taken over maintenance of `beamer`, is looking. :)