# Using \hphantom within TikZ nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I'm trying to align the following piece of text:

*Corresponding author
Name Nameson
name@mydomain.com

such that the two lower lines are horizontally aligned with the C, rather than the * in the first line. To this end, I have tried \hphantom{*}

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) node[inner sep=0pt, below right, text width=\textwidth] {
                      \textsuperscript{*}Corresponding author\\
                      \hphantom{*}Name Nameson\\
                      \hphantom{*}name@mydomain.com};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

but this has no effect on the horisontal alignment. Instead, it gives an additional linebreak, no matter what I use as argument to \hphantom.

How can I achieve the desired alignment?

Comment: try `\strut\hphantom{\textsuperscript{*}}`

Comment: Or [Beamer: effect of newline and hphantom](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69979/beamer-effect-of-newline-and-hphantom)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways, depending on desired alignment.  In the first case, I just left-align a `\Longunderstack` of the desired text following the `\textsuperscript{*}`.  In the second case, I `\llap` the `\textsuperscript{*}`.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,stackengine}
\setstackEOL{\\}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\setstackgap{L}{1\baselineskip}
\draw (0,0) node[inner sep=0pt, below right, text width=\textwidth] {
                      \textsuperscript{*}\Longunderstack[l]{Corresponding author\\
                      Name Nameson\\
                      name@mydomain.com}};
    \end{tikzpicture}

    versus:\smallskip

    \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) node[inner sep=0pt, below right, text width=\textwidth] {
                      \llap{\textsuperscript{*}}Corresponding author\\
                      Name Nameson\\
                      name@mydomain.com};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Egreg mentions that `\hphantom` does not start horizontal mode.  Thus, to fix the problem using your original approach, one must merely leave vertical mode before invoking the `\hphantom`:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) node[inner sep=0pt, below right, text width=\textwidth] {
                      \textsuperscript{*}Corresponding author\\
                      \leavevmode\hphantom{*}Name Nameson\\
                      \leavevmode\hphantom{*}name@mydomain.com};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

`\hphantom` doesn't start horizontal mode and indeed you get blank lines instead of the space you want.

Instead of `\hphantom`, I recommend using `tabular`.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) node[
  outer sep=-1pt,
  inner sep=0pt,
  below right,
  text width=\textwidth
]{\begin{tabular}{@{}r@{}l@{}}
    * & Corresponding author\\
      & Name Nameson\\
      & name@mydomain.com
  \end{tabular}
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that `\textsuperscript{*}` is generally wrong, because the text mode asterisk is already in raised position.

If you want to use `\hphantom`, add `\leavevmode` in front of it.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) node[
  outer sep=-1pt,
  inner sep=0pt,
  below right,
  text width=\textwidth
]{*Corresponding author\\
  \leavevmode\hphantom{*}Name Nameson\\
  \leavevmode\hphantom{*}name@mydomain.com};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The output is the same.

Comment: I know it's a bit hacky, but it comes from the custom poster template that my institute uses. I'm trying not to change too much.